# MySQL delete Foreign Key Constraint, Same Table FK, Deleting all rows not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table, `storage_directory`. And two columns, `directory_id` and `directory`. `directory` has a FK relationship to `directory_id` as a directory can be within a directory in my table.

Although, when I try to delete a directory that references another directory_id I receive a FK constraint fails, even when I am also deleting the referenced directory in the same statement.

| directory_id | directory |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | (null) |
| 222 | 111 |
| 333 | 222 |

`DELETE FROM directories WHERE directory_id IN ('222', '333')`.

I do not understand why this fails, as the result after the delete would not contain a foreign key constraint. Is there a way around this without removing the constraint?

Comment: "In an SQL statement that inserts, deletes, or updates many rows, foreign key constraints (like unique constraints) are checked row-by-row. When performing foreign key checks, InnoDB sets shared row-level locks on child or parent records that it must examine. MySQL checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred to transaction commit." PS Please in code questions give a [mre]. PS This can be expected be a faq. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Does your FK have ON DELETE CASCADE? Please publish your table definitinons.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by updating the column to null before performing a delete. Not ideal, but it works for now. Until I find another solution (or forget about it and put it in production anyways)